# How can I *automatically* backup my contacts in Google Contacts/Gmail?

Tags: backup, osx, linux

On a similar theme to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53863/how-can-i-backup-my-data-in-tripit), how can I ***automatically*** (on a schedule) back up my contacts from Google Contacts/Gmail from the command line (Linux or OS X)? Ideally, this mechanism would be a shell script, so I can run it from [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or similar, and would be free (of cost). I am looking to incorporate this into an automatic backup process - it's easy to do this through the web interface, but not automatically. I'm not too fussy about the target file format, but something like CSV or vCard would be ideal.

The only (unsuitable) solution I've found so far is:

- [GoogleCL](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) - what I used to use, but broken due to recent Google OAuth API changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [GooBook](https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook),
it supports oauth2 and also has a query command which prints what you've searched to `stdout`

```
$ goobook query foo
foo@bar.com     Joe 'Foo' Smith      Group Name
```

It also creates a cache file with I don't know which format which dumps all the address book in a one place whenever you want.

It's probably worth adding that `goobook dump_contacts` seems like the best answer for an automated backup, it dumps all information about all contacts to stdout in some form of Atom feed.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! This seems to work very well. It's probably worth adding that `goobook dump_contacts` seems like the best answer for an automated backup, it dumps all information about all contacts to stdout in some form of Atom feed. If you edit that into your answer, I'll mark this accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a tool I've put together and have been using to pull google contacts information. It's here https://github.com/gedl/gc-csv

I've bumped into this thread searching for such tool, but couldn't find any that does exactly what I needed. This might be useful for others.

Comment: What does this do, exactly? If it isn't a match to the question, why answer?

Comment: It does what is asked in the question. I don't know why you got the impression it does not match the question. I mentioned I didn't find exactly what I needed before posting my answer.  It is not as sophisticated as googlecl (not by a country mile) but can be used to backup the contacts as a cronjob easily. I believe this was the question, and the answer does match.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `goobook`, you can also use [`vdirsyncer`](https://vdirsyncer.pimutils.org/en/stable/).

It can also synchronize both ways, and you can use something like [`khard`](https://github.com/scheibler/khard) to modify the contacts if you want to.

Comment: Excellent answer. vdirsyncer looks very capable! If I have time, I'll take a look at switching over. Thanks.